# Относительные имена в namespace

Tags: php, namespace

Привет всем)) подскажите как правильно сделать..

есть автозагрузка

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
$className = ltrim($className, '\\');
$fileName = '';
$namespace = '';
if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
    $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
    $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
    $fileName = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}
$fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
$fileName = __DIR__ . $fileName;
if (file_exists($fileName)) {
var_dump($fileName);
    require $fileName;
}
});
```

есть файл в проекте /models/File.php

```
namespace models;
class File {
    .....
}
```

есть еще один файл /vendors/core/models/File.php

```
namespace models;
    class File {
    .....
}
```

как правильно обращаться к второму файлу, при том что namespace у него должен быть относительный а не абсолютный.. 
первый работает зашибись.. 
второй инклудится в автозагрузке... но пхп не видит его как класс..
везде где читаю - везде в общем.. а вот как такое решение сделать - не могу найти..
может гуглю не правильно..

пытался через class_alias - не помогло

отключил автозагрузку и просто пытался сделать вот так вот ради интереса

```
$file = include __DIR__ . '\vendor\core\models\File.php';
var_dump($file); //int 1
$file = new File;
```

тоже не помогло..  как только из файла удаляю namespace или дополняю его полным путем - все работает.. 
а мне надо что бы там был относительный путь.. потому что этот файл может обновляться..

Comment: как минимум тут конфиликт имен. в одном неймспейсе 2 одинаковых класса. либо менять имя неймспейса, либо имя класса.

Comment: да.. по другому не получилось)))
Спасибо)